# Generate random string from a list of string with certain probabilities

Tags: java

I am trying to generate random string from list of array string with required probablities in java.i am able to generate random string but dont know how do with probabilities.I have to run program almost 25 - 30 times

```
Probability for abc is 10%
           for def  is 60%
           for ghi is  20%
           for danny is 10%
```

But i am not able to do this.

```
 import java.util.*;

public class newyork
{
public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
{ 
  // othr fun
    public static  void abc()
    {
    //Strings to display
        String [] random = {"abc","def", "ghi","danny"};
   //Pick one by one
        String no1= random[(int) (Math.random()*(random.length))];
        String no2 = random[(int) (Math.random()*(random.length))];
        String no3 = random[(int) (Math.random()*(random.length))];

  //print randomly generated strings
       System.out.println("Here you go : " +  no1 + " " +  no2 + " " + no3 + ");
    }
```

Comment: So, you want random string, based on `probability`. That means higher the probabily, higher is the channce of it to be selected. What is random in this?

Comment: Where in your code are you using the said weighted probabilities? In order for it to work you should try to do *something* with them at least..

Comment: That's the main thing i have no idea how to write a code for Probabilities..

Answer (score 3):

Pseudocode:

```
Generate a random integer n between 0 and 9
if (n==0)        return "abc"
else if (n <= 6) return "def"
else if (n <= 8) return "ghi"
else             return "danny"
```

There are many ways to do this

Answer (score 2):

Basically, to use probabilities, you generate a random number between 0 and 100, not including the 100.

Then, you test for each of the strings in turn, adding the probabilities:

```
String s;
if (number < 10) {s = "abc";}
else if (number < 70) { s = "def";}
else if (number < 90) {s = "ghi";}
else {s = "danny";}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best solution:

```
int number = (int) Math.random() * 100;
String myString;
if(number <= 10)
     myString = "abc";
else if(number <= 20)
     myString = "danny";
else if(number <= 40)
     myString = "ghi";
else
     myString = "def";
```

So that from 0 : 10 it returns abc, 10 : 20 it returns danny, 20 : 40 returns ghi, and 40 : 100 it returns def.
This solution would be horrible with multiple strings / percentages and I am sure that there is a much better way to doing this, but cannot remember (it is on the tip of my tongue.)